# Tweepy can't detect elevated access

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I already have elevated access in my twitter developer account. I already have regenerated the api keys and access token, yet, when I'm trying out this code, I'm still getting an error that I still need elevated access.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
```

The error I'm getting:

```
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve
```

It has been hours since I got my elevated access and all I'm getting when I'm searching this error is to get an elevated access.

I can access the twitter api when using `tweepy.client` but I'm hoping that I can use the perks of an elevated access,

Comment: Have you tried the solutions posted in the [existing twitter dev forum thread on this topic](https://twittercommunity.com/t/403-forbidden-using-tweepy/162435)?

Comment: This page tells me to just use API V2 instead of 1.1. That's what I'm doing with tweepy.client. I'm using V2 with that.